# Problems with Radio Button Group

Tags: android, radio-button

Am trying to use radio button group widget to select gender in my application. Now here is the thing. The user will select a gender and on clicking the button the user will be guided to the respective activity. I wrote the code . The second problem is that my program does nothing though am launching new activities in the if part. I debugged my program to see if the if condition is satisfied seems to me it does. Here is the xml and the .java file

```
public class Gender extends Activity{
     private RadioGroup radioSexGroup;
      private RadioButton radioSexButton;
      private Button btnDisplay;

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gender_asking);

        addListenerOnButton();

      }

      public void addListenerOnButton() {

        radioSexGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioSex);
        btnDisplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gender_button);

        btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
     //****************************
                    int selectedId = radioSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                    // find the radiobutton by returned id
                        radioSexButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
                    if("Iam a Guy!".equals(radioSexButton.getText()))
                    {
                        Intent male_activity = new Intent(Gender.this, Meter.class);
                        startActivity(male_activity);

                    }
                    if("Iam a Girl!".equals(radioSexButton.getText()))
                    {
                        Intent male_activity = new Intent(Gender.this, For_Girl.class);
                        startActivity(male_activity);

                    }

                //********************************     

            }

        });

      }
}
```

and the associated xml is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/hyu_bg"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".KissingMeter" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:text="Tell Us Your Gender!"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioSex"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/gender_button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioMale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/radioFemale"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioFemale"
            android:layout_marginBottom="34dp"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Iam a Guy!" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioFemale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/gender_button"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
            android:text="Iam a Girl!" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/gender_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioSex"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="Lol" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't rely on the text of a `View` in this situation. If you decide to change it later then it will create problems. Most likely, you won't change the `id` of it so just use that. Change it to something like this

```
    btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
           int selectedId = radioSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();  / get the id
           switch (selectedId)   // switch on the button selected
           {
                case R.id.radioMale:
                     Intent male_activity = new Intent(Gender.this, Meter.class);
                     startActivity(male_activity);
                     break;
                case R.id.radioFemale:
                    Intent male_activity = new Intent(Gender.this, For_Girl.class);
                    startActivity(male_activity);
                    break;
                default:
                  Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "No gender selected", 
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  break;
                }

            //********************************     

        }

    });
```